# POST request working fine with POSTMAN/Advance rest client while giving 400 error with HttpUrlConnection

Tags: java, post, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I am a newbie to HttpClient so not sure what's wrong I am doing. I am hitting one POST request through HttpUrlConnection. After sending the request when I check the logs it doesn't hit the entire request. My URL is https://www.example.com/product/pd/v1/gql when I check on the server, for URI, it shows v1/gql and give 400 error.  while the same request works perfectly from Postman and advance rest client.

```
URL obj = new URL("https://www.example.com/product/pd/v1/gql/");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "_bb_vid=djfhhf");
JSONObject val = new JSONObject(gqlValue2);
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
jObj.put(gqlKey1, gqlValue1);
jObj.put(gqlKey2, val);
System.out.println(jObj);

OutputStreamWriter wr = new 
                        OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
wr.write(jObj.toString());
wr.flush();
```

Comment: Is the body sent over HttpClient the same as in PostMan?

Comment: @Argonitas yes, it is same. Only the difference which I found was URI. For Postman, it shows URI as "/product/pd/v1/gql/" while for my code it shows "/v1/gql/"

Comment: where do you see your URL?

Comment: @Argonitas: I am checking in the server logs

Comment: Where are you logging it?

Comment: @Phil: I am doing API testing, but we log every API so whatever request we send those all the request get store in one file